# Nutch crawler not indexing HTML content

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to develop a search functionality where I enter a city name and it gives me the weather conditions for that city.
I have set up Nutch-1.3 and Solr-3.4.0 on my system. The website I am crawling is [here](http://www.imd.gov.in/section/nhac/distforecast/INDIAct.htm) and passing the index to Solr for searching.Now, I want to retrieve the information displayed on [this link](http://www.imd.gov.in/section/nhac/distforecast/delhi.htm), on querying for delhi.

How can I achieve this? Does it require any plugin to be written?

```
 <doc><float name="score">1.0</float><float name="boost">0.1879294</float><str name="content"/><str name="digest">d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e</str><str name="id">http://www.imd.gov.in/section/nhac/distforecast/delhi.htm</str><str name="segment">20111118153543</str><str name="title"/><date name="tstamp">2011-11-18T10:06:45.604Z</date><str name="url">http://www.imd.gov.in/section/nhac/distforecast/delhi.htm</str></doc>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nutch basically crawls through links on the pages.
However, there are no links on the [India page](http://www.imd.gov.in/section/nhac/distforecast/INDIAct.htm%20page) for it to reach the [Delhi page](http://www.imd.gov.in/section/nhac/distforecast/delhi.htm) mentioned by you.
So it won't be able to navigate it down to that page.

You can create your own dummy html page, acting as the start url for indexing, and have all the links you want Nutch to index.

Whats the default search field in you schema ?
Usually its the text field, and querying for delhi would look into that field for matches.
As `*:*` returns the delhi result, and delhi does not. Its not matching the indexed tokens on the field it is searching on.

Whats the field type defined for url in the schema ?
You can copy the field to an other field with text analysis, which would produce the delhi token and querying for `url_copy:delhi` should return you the results.

Comment: Actually, the nutch fetched the Delhi page link but on querying for delhi, it doen't show any result. I have edited my post with snapshot of the XML returned by solr on using "*:*" .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The field type for url is "url" only and what do you mean by "You can copy the field to an other field with text analysis"? How can I achieve this ? Just for a quick check, is it possible to fetch the details on Delhi page(rainfall, Temp etc.) as the source of that page is little wierd?

Comment: The page source also has Delhi. Is it not indexed into some field ? for url find copy field at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields, so you can create a new field with fieldtype text & searching should be able to match url.